# Build a list from a depth map

Tags: code-golf, array, ragged-list

You will be given as input a non-empty list of positive integers.  For example:

```
[1,2,2,2,1]
```

You want to produce a ragged list as output which has this as its "depth map".  This list should have the same elements in the same order but each element `n` should be at the depth equal to its value.

```
[1,[2,2,2],1]
```

This is a list where the `1`s are at the first level, the `2`s are nested in there, the threes would be nested in that etc.

There are multiple outputs that fit this description:

```
[1,[2],[2],[2],1]
[1,[],[2,[],2,2],1]
[1,[2,2,2],1,[[[]]]]
```

We want the simplest one, that is the one with the fewest lists total.  So in this case

```
[1,[2,2,2],1]
```

only has 2 lists whereas all the other examples had more.

### Task

Take a depth map and produce the simplest ragged list that it could represent as outlined above.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as scored in bytes.

### Test cases

```
[1] -> [1]
[2] -> [[2]]
[3] -> [[[3]]]
[10] -> [[[[[[[[[[10]]]]]]]]]]
[1,2] -> [1,[2]]
[2,2] -> [[2,2]]
[2,1,2] -> [[2],1,[2]]
[1,2,3,2] -> [1,[2,[3],2]] 
[1,2,3,3,3,2,1] -> [1,[2,[3,3,3],2],1]
[1,2,1,2,1,3,3,1] -> [1,[2],1,[2],1,[[3,3]],1]
```

Comment: Are commas required to separate the elements in the output it's a string? And can numbers in the input have multiple digits? These seem like they can matter for the natural string-output approach.

Comment: @xnor I can't find any defaults on how to handle lists as strings.  I don't think I am in a position to make a call on what is required there.  I would think space separated or whatever would be fine, but this is probably more of a thing for meta since I don't use languages that way.

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

Input are comma-separated integers, output is in the same format as the test cases.

```
\d+
*[$&$&*]
+`],\[
,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyZFm0srWkVNRU0rlks7IVYnJppL5/9/Qx0jMDTkMuQy4jLmMjTgAgpxGYExiAVSYAynQRCsWAcsC8QgEUMA)

Wraps each number on its own, then repeatedly replaces `],[` with `,`.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>80 79</s>  74 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @tsh*

This builds a weird and dirty string internally but eventually returns a clean ragged list.

```javascript
a=>eval('_='+[...a,'_'].map(g=v=>d^v?d++<v?"["+g(v):"],"+g(v,d-=2):v,d=0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@7boMwFIb3PIXFgi1OnEC2tCZTlg7t0BG5kcWtVARHEFnq01MfQyBFHMsX/d9/Lv5RRnVpW93u20ZneV@IXok4N6qm/kX4QcI5V@BffMmv6kZLYUScfZlTFgSv5uQlXlBSw46eBPeCbCsidrS32DPWvyQbQpJQAvkXux2KiKI1ZFUHD6vQygMO9ws@4DEsncK5YdHLDQGPXtEaduqIF/njnDBXsAY4PJseDQA/Yk1kduGyJdH75EIZnRBOBYeNJJTzxDCdmCRdgtzwQrdnlX5TRURMUt10us55rUv69vnxzrt7WzVlVfzSgipmo/8D)

#### How?

Starting with \$d=0\$, for each entry \$v\$ in the original array followed by an extra `"_"`:

- if the current depth \$d\$ is less than \$v\$: we append the string `"["` repeated \$v-d\$ times before \$v\$ and update \$d\$ to \$v\$
- if \$d\$ is greater than \$v\$: we append the string `"],"` repeated \$d-v\$ times before \$v\$ and update \$d\$ to \$v\$. (NB: The trailing `"_"` triggers this case and closes all pending brackets.)
- if \$d=v\$: we just leave \$v\$ unchanged

We then prepend `"_="`, which implicitly joins everything with commas, and we evaluate the resulting string.

For instance, `[1,2,3,3,3,2,1]` is turned into:

```javascript
"_=[1,[2,[3,3,3,],2,],1,],_"
```

which is evaluated to:

```javascript
[1,[2,[3,3,3],2],1]
```

Comment: Can `join` be replaced by `+''`? `a=>eval('_='+[...a,'_'].map(g=v=>d^v?d++<v?"["+g(v):"],"+g(v,d-=2):v,d=0))`

Comment: @tsh Nice simplification indeed!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,l=0:x and"],"*(l-x[0])+"["*(x[0]-l)+"%s,"%x+f(x[1:],x[0])or"]"*l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU3NisMgEL77FCIUtJ2E2twC6YsED5YkrGBUVJb06bNOY3e7iM73O4Zn/vKu2/dlsHp9TJpuYIdrv1HtJqaAnblttvGqxIWNhSBsbCGnBOy0XZaiyF7BK@IjU@xsd7MGHzNNz0TI4iO11DhkbcqTcW2c9WSNmxMXPaEG/LDqwOdvbcG2KViTOWvuTAhCQzQucwNo8oUbIcCLfZSKNndaBhlvByyzkK6SApBKqK6Ew7/BbxyqIP8kBe9cEaH7LEPZiA369vCU8r8EipgCWVccF/WPYP0FX6wojP8A)

Python's `%` formatter coming in clutch.

Output is a list in string format that can be evaluated by Python to the correct answer.

Simple recursive function that walks down the input list. `l` just stores the value of the last element.

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 71 bytes

```python
lambda x,i=0:",".join((j-i)*"["+(i-(i:=j))*"],"+str(j)for j in x)+i*"]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3RboQgEEXf/QrC01BHU9eXxsT9EesDjZqOQSBANrtfb5nottsQmLn33Bn8I3072374sC/952709jVpcUfq3zuJsl4dWYC1IvUmB1kCVUBdv6osR5RlTAFWtbggVkFW3FVJGcidNu9CEvERi4KpYZpVHdNEtg6zngzZOYLqCkHo@k17mG/aoKmjN5RAVlepVCF8IJuAkCEsQEqhU/vQjKK6ilyK4XK0uWbRniI3LBs8aYMHv@BvHE@j@bNGfOayie3rMOaNPCGejE8e/pdgk1PYnCuOy/5L8PyFXx4ZOf4D)

Using the walrus operator removes the need for recursion, and the trailing comma can be added by `str.join`. Suggested by @loopywalt.

Comment: Non-recursive version that takes advantage of Python's tolerance to trailing commas (-4) https://tio.run/##VY3RboQgEEXf/QrC01BHU9eXxsT9EesDjZqOQSBANrtfb5nottsQmLn33Bn8I3072374sC/952709jVpcUfq3zuJsl4dWYC1IvUmB1kCVUBdv6osR5RlTAFWtbggVkFW3FVJGcidNu9CEvERi4KpYZpVHdNEtg6zngzZOYLqCkHo@k17mG/aoKmjN5RAVlepVCF8IJuAkCEsQEqhU/vQjKK6ilyK4XK0uWbRniI3LBs8aYMHv@BvHE@j@bNGfOayie3rMOaNPCGejE8e/pdgk1PYnCuOy/5L8PyFXx4ZOf4D

Answer (score 6):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 28 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{⟨0⟩:0;1+¨{⊐+`»⊸∨¬×}⊸⊔-1}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KfqDDin6k6MDsxK/CdlYrCqHviipArYMK74oq44oiowqzDl/Cdlal94oq44oqU8J2VqS0xfQoKPuKLiOKfnEbCqCDin6gK4ouIMQrii4gyCuKLiDMK4ouIMTAKMeKAvzIKMuKAvzIKMuKAvzHigL8yCjHigL8y4oC/M+KAvzIKMeKAvzLigL8z4oC/M+KAvzPigL8y4oC/MQox4oC/MuKAvzHigL8y4oC/MeKAvzPigL8z4oC/MQrin6kK)

A single recursive function that builds the output as a nested list.

`⟨0⟩:0` Base case: If the argument is a list containing a single 0, return 0 as a scalar value.

`-1` Decrement each value.
`` {⊐+`»⊸∨¬×}⊸⊔ `` Group adjacent positive integers, and put each 0 in its own group.
`¨` recursively call the function on each group.
`1+` Add 1 to each number.

Comment: Nice approach!  I’ll do a J translation later.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>63 59</sup> 37 bytes

```
<:<@([:>:L:0$:^:(0<{.));.1~1,2~:/\=&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCsIwEETv@YpBpE2grklzW5NSFDwVD14VEaRFvPgBQn89pohNKMPCzgxv9xVWVA7wjBIVNDjOhnA4d8fg2LXywg13rNd8Y6ndh5TakRlNVY@8vfrCBCVOe8LgyTEQgUSou2xYtSR10ZPCAhT94/nGAIM6yuZ27qwQc/5f6lQmZC7zNcunq3ZpJ2XPzA@JMxUmfAE)

<sup>-22 thanks to approach suggested by ovs! It's similar or the same as his BQN answer's.</sup>

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), original approach <sup>63</sup> 59 bytes

```
g=.((,$:/@,&.>/@]^:[~[:(1=*+.1<<.)/,&L.){.),}.@]
[:g/<^:]"+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P91WT0NDR8VK30FHTc9O3yE2ziq6LtpKw9BWS1vP0MZGT1NfR81HT7NaT1OnVs8hlivNVi/aKl3fJs4qVkn7f2pyRr5CmoKhghEQGoMhiGXIxQWTgTGMYAxjLoQmuCQyE0ncEGwqGhdiiSGyIASDJAz/AwA)

This is *ridiculous*.  Someone please find a better approach that still uses boxes and let me know what it is...

The basic approach is:

- Individually wrap each element to its depth.
- Recursively meld together neighboring elements using a fold.

Comment: No J code, but maybe an idea for a slightly different (recursive) *meld* step: Group adjacent boxes (keeping scalar integers separated); For each of those groups: Concatenate the boxes and recursively call on the result. I'm not completely sure if this works correctly and is shorter to implement, but it shouldn't need the `L:`.

Comment: Yes, I considered that and think it’s conceptually more elegant.  Maybe I’ll try tomorrow and see if it’s shorter.  Thanks for looking

Comment: [Found a better approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241683/64121).

Comment: Very, very nice!  Shaved off 22 bytes for my J solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
≔⁰ηＦＡ«Ｆ⁻ηι]→Ｆ⁻ιη[Ｉι≔ιη»Ｆη]ＵＢ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DQEchQ9OaKy2/SEHDM6@gtERDU1OhmosTLOCbmVdarJGho5AJFAwoyswr0VCKVQIq5/TNL0vVsArKTM8oAXGRVGeCDISrjgarhnCcE4tLNIAmAQWglmdCLK@FWJ@BakdwaolTYnJ2elF@aV6KhpIOUOz//@hoQx0jHQg2BkLD2Nj/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰η
```

Start with a depth of 0.

```
ＦＡ«
```

Loop through the depths.

```
Ｆ⁻ηι]
```

Add `]`s as necessary to reduce the depth to the current depth.

```
→
```

Leave a space between values.

```
Ｆ⁻ιη[
```

Add `]`s as necessary to increase the depth to the current depth.

```
Ｉι
```

Output the current depth.

```
≔ιη
```

Save the current depth as the previous depth.

```
»Ｆη]
```

Output the necessary closing `]`s at the end.

```
ＵＢ,
```

Replace all the interior spaces with commas. (The leading space simply gets skipped, since it wasn't actually printed.)

Actually creating the list in memory takes 44 bytes:

```
⊞υ⟦⟧ＦＡ«Ｗ‹Ｌυι«≔⟦⟧θ⊞§υ±¹θ⊞υθ»≔…υιυ⊞§υ±¹ι»⭆¹§υ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYw9C8IwEIbn9FdkvIMIVsdOpZOgUnAsHUqNSSCktUn8QPrbY2oVdJHj7jje555WNkPbNTqE0lsJntGqxiw5dQOFjem9A0T6SMhVKs0pbLm1cRjhIouMqjklubVKGKhqRs/xnZCXLXcbc@S3ybrnonEcUsQfwr@vMfkoinureSG7fspUpP2U/9OpCIxJOSjj4ODiErumh5TRL36JiFkIVZWyFZt7HSut67C46Cc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⟧
```

Start with an empty list.

```
ＦＡ«
```

Loop over the depths.

```
Ｗ‹Ｌυι«
```

While the next depth is larger than the current depth, ...

```
≔⟦⟧θ⊞§υ±¹θ⊞υθ
```

... nest a list.

```
»≔…υιυ
```

Truncate the current depth to the next depth.

```
⊞§υ±¹ι
```

Append the next depth value to its list.

```
»⭆¹§υ⁰
```

Pretty-print the final list.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εDG…[ÿ]]',ý…[ÿ]…],[',:
```

Input as list, output as string. It kinda feels like cheating, but I saw multiple other answers do the same.. And I guess we could technically add an eval.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FYX90cNy6IP74@NVdc5vBfKBlKxOtHqOlb//0cb6hjpQLAxEBrGAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c1td3B81LIs@vD@2tlZd5/BeKAdIxepEq@tY/df5Hx1tGKujEG0EIoxBhKEBmNQBixjBKCgfSOkYIzNBECgLE4BgkKBhbCwA).

A port of [*@xigoi*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241653/52210) is 22 bytes as well:

```
0.ø¥Ý€{.±…,[]sèJI.ιJ¦¨
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQO/wjkNLD8991LSmWu/QxkcNy3SiY4sPr/Dy1Du30@vQskMr/v@PNtQx0oFgYyA0jAUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/A73DOw4tPTz3UdOaar1DGx81LNOJji0@vMKrUu/cTq9Dyw6t@K/zPzraMFZHIdoIRBiDCEMDMKkDFjGCUVA@kNIxRmaCIFAWJgDBIEHD2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε         # Map over each integer in the (implicit) input-list:
 D        #  Duplicate the integer
  G       #  Pop and loop the integer-1 amount of times:
   …[ÿ]   #   Wrap it in block-quotes as string
]         # Close both the inner loop and outer map
 ',ý     '# Join the strings with "," delimiter
    …[ÿ]  # Wrap the entire string into block-quotes as well
…],[',:  '# Replace all "],[" with ","
          # (after which the resulting string is output implicitly)

0.ø       # Surround the (implicit) input-list with leading/trailing 0
   ¥      # Get the deltas/forward-differences of this list
    Ý     # Transform each value to a list in the range [0,value]
     €{   # Sort each inner list
       .± # Convert each to its sign (-1 if <0; 0 if 0; 1 if >0)
…,[]sè    # Modular 0-based index each into ",[]"
      J   # Join each inner list of characters to a string
I.ι       # Interleave it with the input-list
   J      # Join it together again
    ¦¨    # Remove the leading/trailing ","
          # (after which the resulting string is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I'm surprised nobody came up with a “non-cheating” way that would be shorter.

Comment: @xigoi _ovs_' BQN answer seems to be a non-cheating approach. Not sure if porting it to Jelly or 05AB1E would shorten the string approach, though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
Ø0jIr0Ṣ€Ṡị“[],”ż⁸FḊṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDIMszyKDhzsXPWpa83Dngoe7ux81zImO1XnUMPfonkeNO9we7uh6uHPa////ow11jHQg2BgIDXVMYgE)

A string-based approach.

### Explanation

```
Ø0jIr0Ṣ€Ṡị“[],”ż⁸FḊṖ
Ø0j                  Surround with zeroes
   I                 Increments
    r0               Raplace each element x with the range x..0
      Ṣ€             Sort each range
        Ṡ            Replace each number with its sign
         ị“[],”      Perform the mapping: 1 -> "[", -1 -> "]", 0 -> ","
               ż⁸    Zip with the original input
                 F   Flatten
                  ḊṖ Remove the leading and trailing commas
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>59</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
f@{a:0..}=a
f@l_:=f/@SplitBy[l-1,Sign]+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/NoTrRykBPr9Y2kSvNISfeyjZN3yG4ICezxKkyOkfXUCc4Mz0vVtvwf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDcqxaXXByYl5dNVe1Ya0OV7URiDAGEYYGYFIHLGIEo6B8IKVjjMwEQaAsTACCQYKGtVy1/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 112 bytes:

```
from itertools import*
f=lambda x,n=1:[j for a,b in groupby(x,key=lambda x:x==n)for j in(b if a else[f(b,n+1)])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHRboQgEEWf61dMfBHa6aasL40J/RFrGky1dYtAxDb69XYm4naLQZjLuTNhCOv86V35HKZt6yc/wjB30@y9jTCMwU/zfdZra8b23cCCTquqvkDvJzDYwuDgY/LfoV3Fgl/degWrRWsnGbsQJIjswUBnY1f3okX3oGQjm22vACbOWQSd53mtGnh8AVqy@rxvaaWgTAFtOFRPR5wGCddBx5jMCnf7Ga/ZMAnqT2rw4EjE8taMVJAdcJzxR@Z/BItMoUop9sn6DZiq8J8tDeN05Yy7NHAr4ykGO8yieHWFrLI77rCG0QRBDTpZfhhj37ofYxGGg@X0hZREx0gPB70wUut2@wU)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```
f=->a,d=1{a.chunk{_1>d}.flat_map{_1 ? [f[_2,d+1]]:_2}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVDbasMwDKWv_gqRp7VTQpXCGIVmH-IZ4zU1DUuz0CWDUfIle-nD9lHt10zCTi8ytnSOzpFBP7_7_u37ePzrO58-n578Ki0clis6uGy97Zv3g6WiHDJfu87uXMsQXkB7bXMsH8mYpc2HIbjPk5n_2EMFVQOJJgNpAZyUzkPJmcEiAi4E0nzEMZi4BLcxmgmDPcfLNIwEXSmDo45JXNyakT8UB4w9OWy-UwgpKqQ4Ilzhb4TxF3nFYkSeZJ9tXXUPyWuTTDPZ1ObL1WAp8HpuBtWC15VRm6ZUKqxsXPw_)

-16 from AZTECCO.

Comment: Nice answer! I think you can remove "a.all?{_1==d}?a:"

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p, 86 bytes

```perl
s/\d+,?|$/"]"x($d=$l-$&).","."["x-$d.($l=$&)/ge;s/(\[),|,(])|,(,)/$1$2$3/g;s/^.|..$//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYlBCsIwEEX3HmMYJMFJxqS4kuJB0rhqCUKwpXXRRc9unNAuZHiP@f9Pw5xvpSzc9Rd6bMgQYVXYt5gNnrUFAgsBVoO9VZhb6TgN94VVFzRtpKIWkWZ06LHhJNPTbtYicyoluHgKXmgEd62iGv3hPYmp@fvqyXbkndq5@B2nz2t8L8VM@Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 84 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 77 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with a `\`.

```r
f=function(v,s=1)"if"(all(v<s),v,{y[]=cumsum(c(T,y<-v==s)|y);Map(f,split(v,y),s+1)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1LuUT8zKk_OaDLtmpg4YS-vE-DQlpYLwWbKDUBVzGBeBuScasDenpyqkI##jZBNCoMwEIX3PYW4ytARHF1qeoPuutMsRAgImkqjAWl7dptQKfhDdUJmk/e9eZPHOEoue1V21V0xg5oT@JX0WVHXzKQa0OBzyAQv@0b3DSvZDYc0MJxreA2QXIuWSdRtXXWWHgD1meANo7RKAkjKomO@F1y8jESugmXlKlc@nJw6mqmzSOzo47k@i8UeQeECmYpC8asdB5ynJNzPGeFyMzzA0IoSeGSa5TDeSIn2f9xc7wjujo2wZeLenBHSgSDf65i117SO685V/HUcPw)

Outputs the actual list structure.

Comment: I thought this would be a great moment to use the obscure `relist` but I couldn't figure out how to build the list structure. Trying to incorporate `relist` into your answer gives me [85 bytes](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR1LuUT8zKk_OaDLtmpg4YS-vE-DQlpYLwWbKDUBVzGBeBuScasDenpyqkI##jZBNCoMwEIX3PYW4ysAIJi7V3qAniFmINCBoKv6BtD17mqFS8IfqhGSRvO/Nm7TW6lQPpujLh2EjtPeq7Ho2ol9qn@Vmcnf4nKRKi6HuhpoVjOOUBGMi4DVBfMsbprFrqtJBgXsCeOMIYDUpAeIi75nvBVdPcpWZYF2ZyYwPF1KLhVoKdaCPlnoZqSOChytkLh6qXx044DIlx@OcAteT4QmGbyiFZ7o5DqOdlOj@h/p6Z3BaLsKeCb2REfITQb6bmK3XPA6d5Kr@OtoP).

Comment: Though I suppose `relist` could be used for [this other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242174/67312) plus your solution here once you build the inverted depth map

Comment: @Giuseppe, thanks, that's a nice function I've never heard of before. I'm working on a solution to this other question, but as other answers base on solutions from here, I thought this challenge needs an R answer first :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.4.1) `D`, 20 bytes

```
Ġƛh‹(w);S`⟩|⟨`\|øVḢṪ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%C4%A0%C6%9Bh%E2%80%B9%28w%29%3BS%60%E2%9F%A9%7C%E2%9F%A8%60%5C%7C%C3%B8V%E1%B8%A2%E1%B9%AA&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C2%2C3%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C2%2C1%2C3%2C2%5D&header=&footer=)

A big mess. We're using v2.4.1 because v2.6+ prettyprint lists with spacing.

```
Ġ                    # Group consecutive identical elements
 ƛ     ;             # Map...
  h‹( )              # item-1 times...
     w               # wrap in a list
        S            # Stringify
         `⟩|⟨`\|øV   # Replace `⟩|⟨` with `|`
                  ḢṪ # Remove the first and last characters.
```